# Google search on customer entered keyword in PHP

Tags: php, web-crawler, google-search

I have a UI where customer enters combination(key word description of a product) of keywords. Using those key words I want to get results using google in my site. In short, I'm using google to search product results of my site. In the UI, I want to show first three links when a user enters keywords in a search text input box.  Any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: Have a look into the [Google Custom Search API](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/overview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.google.com/enterprise/search/products_gss.html

Sounds like you need Google Site Search.